# Different Outputs for Different Tracks

Tags: logic-pro, live, logic

Hi im wondering if its possible to have (for example) two tracks in the same project but have each track go to a different output?

In this case i have a DI bass and a DI guitar, id like to route them to their own amps respectively and have them play simultaneously when the track starts but with each track coming from their own amp.

Im using logic on mac and have an Allen & Heath Zed R16 16ch mixer/interface.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Those desks used ADAT or Firewire to connect… What Mac do you have, what OS & how are you connected up to it?

Comment: Im using firewire to connect, it's a 2011 macbook running high sierra, think it's logic X, its probably just about the only mac "new enough" to connect to the desk and install the firmware

Comment: Then it ought to be possible, I'd think… unfortunately it's not a system I've ever seen, so not sure how to go about it, sorry. I do get your point on 'new enough' - my entire studio is built around several Mac Pros still on Mojave, so I don't have to re-buy a whole lot of interfaces & software not supported afterwards. I'm not keen on spending 10 grand to have nothing but a newer version of everything that already works perfectly. Wish you luck :)